# PG::AdminShutdown: FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, activerecord, sinatra

I had perfectly working sinatra rails app working under AWS among with posgtgresql database. One day, without any actions from my side backend stopped working. I checked the logs - every call to backend that engages ActiveRecord fails like this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server
```

To me it sounds like the backend lost connection to the database. But the instance is working fine. I even logged in to db directly via console and executed some queries.

It could get broken after I did those queries from the console, but these were just simple selects, no db altering at all. I tried rebooting the instance.

I know it's not much - please specify what information I should provide to investigate it further.

EDIT: 
I've investigated logs further and found this:

```
PG::AdminShutdown: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

It was first error, then the app lost the connection to the database for good. Happened 2 days ago. I was executing those queries week ago, so it wasn't the case. This literally happened itself for no reason. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know the answer to this but I've managed to fix this by redeploying new version of backend. Rebooting instance or server did not help.